# Visual Studio Code Snippet Object acting the same as Literal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, code-snippets

I've recently started creating my own code snippets for Visual Studio 2013. One of the things I've been trying to do is to use the Object replacement. Although I define a type, it doesn't seem to act any differently from the Literal replacements. It doesn't matter what I type in, it doesn't show any warning or whatever.

Is Object still supported in VS C#, or is it now just falling back to Literal, or am I missing something?

Comment: My answer support your question?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN vs2013 custom code snippets tutorial:

> You can provide two types of replacements: literals and objects

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Look for **Adding Replacement** section in the source link above.

Hope that answers your question...

Comment: I understand that they are two types of replacements, but functionally I cannot see a difference, the additional type parameter seems to have no effect.